# Cannot understand a line in HashMap.java code

Tags: java, hashmap

I was going through HashMap.java and in the function getNode(...),
I came across three things I didn't understand:

```
    final Node<K,V> getNode(int hash, Object key) {
    Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> first, e; int n; K k;
    if ((tab = table) != null && (n = tab.length) > 0 &&
        (first = tab[(n - 1) & hash]) != null) {
        if (first.hash == hash && // always check first node
            ((k = first.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
            return first;
        if ((e = first.next) != null) {
            if (first instanceof TreeNode)
                return ((TreeNode<K,V>)first).getTreeNode(hash, key);
            do {
                if (e.hash == hash &&
                    ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
                    return e;
            } while ((e = e.next) != null);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Firstly, why are they comparing hashcode and key both? Should one comparison not be enough?

Secondly, why even store hashcode in the node when collision is possible.

Thirdly, this if condition :
`(k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k)))`
seems like the part after the OR should be enough.

Can someone shed some light into this design decision please!

Comment: `why are they comparing hashcode and key both`  I'm guessing it's because the hash is a much cheaper check.  So just compare the hash first before calling `equals()`, which might be a good deal more expensive.

Comment: `Thirdly, this if condition` The first part of that compares for the *same object* and also allows for both `e.key` and `key` to be both null.  It's both (again) a cheaper check than calling `equals()` and also in this case part of the spec, that allows `Map` to store a `null` key.

Comment: The hash is the fast primary check. Then however equality has to be checked (as hashCode need not be unique). Equality is expensive. You also see the alternative, or Object equaltiy, `==`, being tested first, as that is faster than a general `.equals`. As key is passed in, it could be null; a bit weird case. Just defensive programming.